# cypress cucumber error Step implementation missing for: Given User checks out user with role TestRole and auth testAut

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I'm getting cypress error Step implementation missing for:
*Given User checks out user with role TestRole and auth testAut.*

Feature File:

```
Feature: Initial Test
    Scenario Outline: Test file to test feature files.
        Given User checks out user with role <role> and auth <aut>
        And User visit home page
        Then User click sign in link on the top right of the page

        Examples:
            | role    | aut   |
            | TestRole | testAut |
```

Step definition file:

```
Given('User checks out user with role {string} and auth {string}', (role,aut) => {
    cy.log('Inside check out user step!!!!!')
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{string} is the cucumber expression for a *quoted* string. So you probably have to write in your scenario

```
Given User checks out user with role "<role>" and auth "<aut>"
```

can you try that out?

Another option is to include the quotes in the table instead:

```
Examples:
            | role    | aut   |
            | TestRole | "testAut" |
```